# Google Maps Clustering in Android

Tags: android

I am doing map clustering in Android, but i only get markers on the map instead of clusters. Can someone help me? Code is here:

```
 for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
                                clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(PozicijeSvihVozilaActivity.this, googleMap);
                                googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
                                googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
                                LatLng position = new LatLng(formatCoordinate(list.get(j).getLatitude()), formatCoordinate(list.get(j).getLongitude()));
                                String title = list.get(j).getReg_broj();
                                List<MyItem> clusterItem = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
                                clusterItem.add(new MyItem(position, title));
                                clusterManager.addItems(clusterItem);
                                clusterManager.cluster();
                                CustomClusterRenderer renderer = new CustomClusterRenderer(PozicijeSvihVozilaActivity.this, googleMap, clusterManager);
                                clusterManager.setRenderer(renderer);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added all the code inside the for-loop so it is getting executed everytime. You just need to keep the code to add latitude, longitude values to the arraylist inside the for loop, everything else needs to be outside.

```
clusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(PozicijeSvihVozilaActivity.this, googleMap);
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);

List<MyItem> clusterItem = new ArrayList<MyItem>();

for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
    LatLng position = new LatLng(formatCoordinate(list.get(j).getLatitude()), formatCoordinate(list.get(j).getLongitude()));
    String title = list.get(j).getReg_broj();
    clusterItem.add(new MyItem (position, title));
}

clusterManager.addItems(clusterItem);
clusterManager.cluster();
CustomClusterRenderer renderer = new CustomClusterRenderer(PozicijeSvihVozilaActivity.this, googleMap, clusterManager);
clusterManager.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have one cluster with 9 items. How to set zoom level and if i zoom out to show markers instead of cluster circle?

Comment: To set the zoom level, you need to use the moveCamera or animateCamera methods in the google maps object and pass a new CameraUpdate instance with the new zoom level you want. About your second question, I'm not sure. Please search further for the answer